# ¿Cómo crear una url amigable estilo Wordpress usando mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

Intento configurar a través de mod_rewrite urls amigables del tipo Wordpress. Pasar de esta url

```
Repertorio/historia.php?serie=2&historia=7
```

A esta url

```
Repertorio/nombre_de_la_serie/nombre_de_la_historia
```

Hasta ahora he configurado el htaccess usando esta configuración

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Repertorio/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).htm?$ 
Repertorio/historia.php?serie=$1&historia=$2 [L,NC]
```

Y el resultado es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se darán cuenta, la url no sale como quisiera que salga, pero al menos me responde a la url configurada en el htaccess. No obstante, verán que no me sale nada en la página. Revisé la página muy a fondo y me encontré con que el servidor ahora no encuentra los demás objetos que la compone.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que mi pregunta inicial ahora se han vuelto dos: ¿Cómo puedo configurar el htaccess para que me genere urls amigables como el mostrado arriba? y ¿Por qué ahora mi server no encuentra los elementos que componen la página? (Esta última no sé si se entiende bien, pero cualquier cosa se vale preguntar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, pude resolver el problema. Lo de la configuración para generar la url amigable en htaccess está bien como me lo plateaste @Mariano, pero tuve que hacerle unos ligeros cambios a esta, dejándolo de esta manera, ya que así fue como me funcionó:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)\.php$ historia.php?serie=$1&historia=$2 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

No obstante, estaba estudiando un poco sobre la naturaleza de estas urls amigables, y descubrí algo curioso: En los casos en los que se quería usar variables como éstas para url amigable:

```
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/NombreaDeLaSerie/NombreDeLaHistoria.php
```

Se hace necesario cambiar algunas variables en la sintaxis de búsqueda de MySQL. Es decir, no necesariamente tienen porqué mostrarse de primero los datos que tengan las columnas con una variable ID tal, como en este caso:

```
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/historia.php?serie=1&historia=1
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/historia.php?serie=1&historia=2
etc.
```

En los ejemplos anteriores, podemos ver un típico caso de url dinámica. Ahora bien, si lo que queremos es modificar estas url para que salgan como si fuera urls estáticas o permalinks, normalmente se agregan unos códigos en el archivo .htaccess, haciendo un llamado al módulo mod_rewrite. Por lo que quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)\.php$ historia.php?serie=$1&historia=$2 [L,NC]
```

El resultado sería algo así como ésto:

```
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/1/1.php
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/1/2.php
etc.
```

En mi caso, quería que fuera como en el primer ejemplo, pero hasta ahora @Mariano, me diste una idea con la configuración que me pusiste anteriormente. Y si, no es la misma que apliqué en mi archivo porque tuve que modificarlo para que salga como una url fácilmente recordable, casi del estilo Wordpress.

No obstante, para hacer esto en parte posible, tuve que modificar algunas variables en mi script de configuración de MySQL en el archivo php donde estoy ejecutando las consultas, haciendo que en lugar de que se muestren los datos cuya variable se base en una columna determinada (por ejemplo, en la columna ID), se muestren los datos cuya variable se base en otra columna (por ejemplo en la columna que contiene los nombres de la serie y de las historias). No sé si me entiendo hasta aquí.

El caso es que, para hacer esto posible, tuve que hacer todo lo anteriormente mencionado para que finalmente me salga como yo quería que saliese. No obstante, hubo el problema de que ahora, todo enlace a archivos CSS, imágenes y demás que componían la página se habían roto, haciendo creer al servidor que estos elementos estaban allí, pero como no los encontró, suponiendo que tales archivos eran fijos pero no accesibles, los marcó como 404 Not found. El resultado, una página completamente en blanco cuyos elementos y datos no salían. Yo me dí cuenta de que la redirección de la url amigable funcionaba a la perfección, porque si me iba por una variable tal, que ya existiera en mi base de datos, ésta se me aparecía y no me salía el clásico error 404. sólo la página en blanco era el siguiente problema a resolver.

Y ya googleando por un rato, me topé con que habría que ponerle el siguienre código al head del archivo para que salgan los elementos. Y con eso finalmente quedó.

```
<base href="http://dominio.com" />
```

El resultado, una página cuya url dinámica real salió como permalink o estática.

```
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/nombreserie/nombrehistoria.php
```

Gracias a las pruebas de ensayo y error, se aprenden mucho de estas cosas. Y la verdad, tras muchos ratos de pruebas, estrés, googleando algo de info en páginas como ésta, mucho rato frente a la computadora y, claro, mucha paciencia, finalmente pude conseguir hacer una url estática, quizás mejor que las que se muestran por default en CMS como en Wordpress. Por el momento, estoy contento con el resultado.

Para quien esté con problemas con la creación de su url amigable, estos métodos antes enseñados podría serles de utilidad. Sólo es cuestión de hacer pruebas y así dar con el resultado.

Saludos a todos y buen día.

Comment: Hasta donde describiste, entiendo que es exactamente lo mismo que te respondí... En cuanto a la modificación en el PHP es un tema completamente diferente (que no está relacionado a la pregunta en sí -obviamente Apache no puede adivinar el número de ID que está en la base de datos a partir del nombre). Por otro lado, en cuanto a los otros recursos (CSS, imágenes y demás), el .htaccess no tiene nada que ver con eso. Tu regla sólo se aplica a urls terminadas en `.htm`, no para otras extensiones.

Comment: En vez de cambiar el `<base>`, creo que hubiese sido más intuitivo acceder a los recursos de alguna de las siguientes formas: **1.** cambiando la url -en vez de acceder a `image/nombre.jpg`, cambiarlo por `/image/nombre.jpg`, o **2.** generando una regla en el .htaccess que se aplique para esos recursos. Por ejemplo, `RewriteRule ^Repertorio/[a-z0-9]+/image/([^/]*)$ image/$1 [NC,L]` y lo mismo para el resto

Comment: Puede ser una buena idea implementar esa regla en el. htaccess. Tan pronto como tenga tiempo lo implmentaré de esa manera. Muchas gracias @Mariano por la ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás buscando es **reescribir** una URL.

No sé por qué en este tema de las URLs amigables siempre encuentro preguntas describiendo el objetivo al revés. La idea es reescribir de:

```
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/NombreaDeLaSerie/NombreDeLaHistoria.htm
```

a:

```
http://dominio.com/Repertorio/historia.php?serie=NombreaDeLaSerie&historia=NombreDeLaHistoria
```

Apache tiene que reescribir, convirtiendo el primero en el segundo, de forma transparente para el usuario. El navegador muestra y accede a la primera, pero en el servidor internamente se accede a la segunda.

Esto se logra con esta línea en el .htaccess:

```py
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Repertorio/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)\.htm$ Repertorio/historia.php?serie=$1&historia=$2 [L,NC]
```

> - Tener en cuenta que sólo acepta letras de a a z (sin acentos, sin guiones) y números, pero se podrían agregar más a la clase de caracteres. Por ejemplo `[-_a-záéíóúüñ0-9]`, o lo que quieras.
> - El modificador `[NC]` (no case) hace que ignore mayúsculas/minúsculas, que no sea necesario especificar ambos casos.
> - El punto es un caracter especial en regex, y se tiene que escapar como `\.` para que sea interpretado como literal.

Eso es todo. El resto de los problemas descriptos en tu pregunta no están relacionados a esta reescritura. Si tu .htaccess sólo tiene estas líneas, y tu script en PHP no presenta errores, todo va a funcionar.

Comment: @MauroMartin ninguna de las URLs de CSS, fuentes o scripts coincide con la regla que publiqué en esta respuesta. Si hay más reglas en tu .htaccess podrías realizar una nueva pregunta dando el detalle completo. Es decir, tu .htaccess completo, ejemplos de URLs que debería reescribir, a que URL tiene que escribir, y ejemplos de CSS u otros recursos en los que no debería reescribir pero falla. De lo contrario, es imposible que adivinemos tu problema